# Multiple Select option with two different array

Tags: php

I am trying to display a select box with multiple select

I have two array one for option value `$course` another for `$selected_course`

here is my code kindly review it and inform me where I have done my mistake.

```
$course =stdClass Object
(
    [Id] => 4
    [name] => EME
    [desc] => 
    [details] => 
    [created_by] => 0
    [created_on] => 2016-01-01 23:47:15
    [ip] => 
    [status] => 0
)

$selected_course= Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 2
)
```

**Now here is my code:**

```
<?php     
    $i=0;
    foreach ($courses as $course) {
    $select_Course=explode(',',$center->course) ;
?>
    <option <?php echo (isset($select_Course[$i]) || $select_Course[$i]==$course->Id)?'selected':false;?>  value="<?=$course->Id;?>"><?=$course->name;?></option>
<?php 
    $i++;
} ?>
```

Its not selecting anyone of them why ?? I have tried `in_array` , `array_search` but failed

Comment: just check what you get in `$select_Course[$i]` and `$course->Id`.

Comment: now i have change my logic `<option <?php echo (array_search($course->Id, $select_Course))?'selected':false;?>` but its also not giving me the proper result

Comment: So the `$courses` array contains all `$course` object, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$courses` array contains all the course objects, then your code should be like this:

```
<select multiple>
    <?php
        foreach($courses as $course){
            $option = "<option value=\"{$course->Id}\"";
            if(in_array($course->Id, $selected_course)){
                $option .= " selected";
            }
            $option .= ">{$course->name}</option>";
            echo $option;
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Man . Its Works Perfectly .